# How to Make Hazelnut Roasted Coffee

Tags: substitutions, coffee, roast

I live in Madrid and am about to run out of hazelnut-flavored coffee beans brought over as contraband from the last time we visited the States. I am desperate for my hazelnut-flavored morning fix, but am unwilling to pay $20/pd. to import beans from the UK or risk having a shipment get caught in customs in the next care package from the States.

I would love to know if and how (1) I can roast coffee beans in my apartment and (2) how to make them hazelnut-flavored.

I am not interested in flavored syrup as an alternative.

Thank you!

Comment: I know that at a local coffee roaster, (The Roasterie), the way they make flavored coffee is to soak the roasted beans in flavored syrup.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I will look into that possibility.

Comment: I think this really should be two completely separate questions. I can give a very thorough answer for how to roast beans, but know nothing about hazelnut flavoring.

Comment: Also, check out [coffeegeek.com](http://www.coffeegeek.com/forums) for some excellent coffee information

Comment: Also, also, take a look at the related threads on the right. [This one may be interesting](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7440/is-there-a-way-to-infuse-roasted-coffee-beans-with-different-flavors).

Answer (score 4):

There's a number of different ways you can add flavouring to coffee. As previously suggested, you can add syrup to the beans or to the finished coffee but the problem with syrup generally is that whilst adding flavouring it also adds sweetness which some may not want.

You could try adding hazlenut essence or oil to the pre-roasted beans and leave for a few days for the flavours to infuse before grinding and using.

Or you could try adding whole hazlenuts to pre-roasted beans in a ratio of about 2:1 beans to hazlenuts by weight and leaving for a few days for the flavours to infuse and then grind and use.

You'd need to experiment with quantities and leave time to find what works best for you.

I don't think it's practical to roast beans in the home.

Comment: Home roasting is not just practical, it's kinda fun and can be much cheaper than buying roasted beans. Go a Behmor, or for small cramped apartments the Korean iCoffee.

Comment: It's interesting you mention that is *is practical* to roast coffee beans in the home but then go on to cite the need to purchase two specific appliances to enable you to do so. My comment was intended for the home *without* any specialist equipment. But I'm beginning to realise that unless you **spell things out** people will *always* misinterpret your intended meaning.

Comment: I mentioned 2 home roasters. You only need one of them! The question does not mention that new equipment is out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

As for the first question (if you can roast in your apartment), it is certainly possible, and can be very practical. I roast coffee in my apartment with a cheap popcorn popper (similar to [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0085BAO84)). It is very easy. See [sweetmarias.com](http://www.sweetmarias.com) for a lot of helpful hints.

I would also like to know the answer to the second question!